# Can I enable a paywall with specific permisions inWordPress?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm learning to code, and I know the basics to get a WebApp up and running with react + firebase and also have done some Laravel tutorials but right now I need to ship something as quick as possible since I'm at an accelerator. 
I know WordPress has the themes and plugins but not sure if I will be able to tie everything together.
Basically what I need is a kind of reddit with a paywall. So I know I can integrate Stripe with some plugins, but will I be able to give access to members to specific groups without much trouble?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With your level of coding knowledge (if I understood you correctly), I might recommend trying or at least starting with [a Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/paywall/). If you're feeling up to it, you might try something like [this tutorial](https://www.wpsuperstars.net/setup-paywall-with-wordpress/) to create a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

A basic PHP server is pretty handy (XAMPP, LAMP, etc.) and super quick to get up and running (since almost anyone will host it for cheap).  Another great approach is Code.xyz (https://code.xyz/) or even Runkit (https://runkit.com/).

Hope that helps!